How do I create a decile column in Python polars?
Let's say I have a column of FICO scores. I'd like to create another column FICO_DECILE that ranks the FICO scores descending and assigns a decile group, i.e. FICO=850 would have FICO_DECILE=1, and something like FICO=360 would have FICO_DECILE=10.
I tried:
# decile rank
df1 = df.with_columns(
    (
      (pl.col('fico').rank(method='dense')/df.height*10).cast(pl.UInt32).alias('fico_decile')
    )
)

But I only get DECILE_GROUP equal to 0 and null.

Can you provide a minimum reproducible example?

I have not tested but this should work, overall, I think you are on the right track, The main reason why you are getting that error is basically how you are using rank().
The trick is to use descending: bool = False
I have modified your code to include this.
df1 = df.with_columns(
    (
        (pl.col('fico').rank(method='min', descending=True) / df.height * 10)
        .ceil()
        .cast(pl.UInt32)
        .alias('fico_decile')
    )
)

Since you are getting null values we could do a bit of data wrangling here
see ref: lit
# filter out null FICO scores
fico_df = df.filter(pl.col('fico').is_not_null())

# rank for non-null FICO scores
fico_df = fico_df.with_columns(
    (
        (pl.col('fico')
         .rank(method='min', descending=True)  
         / fico_df.height * 10)  
        .ceil()
        .cast(pl.UInt32) 
        .alias('fico_decile')
    )
)

# handle null with lit 
null_fico_df = df.filter(pl.col('fico').is_null()).with_columns(
    pl.lit(None).alias('fico_decile')
)


# df with valid and invalid
df_final = pl.concat([fico_df, null_fico_df])

# results
df_final.select(['fico', 'fico_decile']).show()


@kstats9pt3 I think it isdescending=True see ref

Thank you. I think this is close, but it doesn't create 10 groups. I have a group equal to null which makes sense because there are invalid fico, but then I only have groups 1-8 after that. Why wouldn't this create 11 groups (1-10 plus a null)?

Still only creates 8 groups, 1-8, instead of 10 groups. Any idea why?

@kstats9pt3 would you like to retain your null values ? I suspect that it ignores it because you can't rank null I guess, it is either you figure a way to change it to an alias.

I was referencing the full dataframe with null values in the height reference so it works great now! I will mark as answered, thanks again.
